# Proving the following claim for MST (Minimum Spanning Trees)?

Tags: graph, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree, proof-of-correctness

I want to prove the following claim for undirected and connected graph, Spanning Tree (T) and weight function with real numbers:

> $T$ is a **minimum** spanning tree in $G=(V,E)$ **iff** for every edge
> $e=u-v$ in $E$ the weight of it is bigger or equal to the heaviest
> edge in the only (simple) path between $u$ and $v$ in $T$

If $T$ is a **minimum** spanning tree in $G=(V,E)$ it's easy to prove the claim, but what about the other direction?

I've no clue, plus I tried to assume that $T$ is NOT a **minimum** spanning tree in $G=(V,E)$ and try to reach a contradiction, but that assumption doesn't seem to add much of information (if a spanning tree isn't MST then what can I see more than that)?

Comment: Why $$ tags don't work here, (they used to work at: math.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Seems like a maths question, rather than programming.  Probably should be on another site.

Comment: They still work at math.stackexchange.com :) This has something to do with the fact that, it is precisely where your question should be. Note that ```python tags do not work at math.stackexchange for the same reason: code questions should be here not there.

Comment: That being said, I agree that sometimes, even for a code question or answer, $$ tags would be useful. But well, in your case, it is because it is a math question not a coding question.

Answer (score 0):

Let T satisfy the condition, let us prove that it is a MST.

By contradiction, if it is not there is a different MST S. Let (u,v) be in S and not in T, if we remove it from S we are left with a graph S' with exactly two connected components. Now observe (hint : T is spanning) there is at least one edge (a,b) != (u,v) in T that connects them. By the condition, (a,b) has a smaller weight than (u,v), so if we add it to S' we obtain a spanning tree with smaller weight than S, which is absurd since S was supposed to be a MST.

Conclusion : T is a MST.